# Unable to clone DNN site from Sandbox to Prod

Tags: sql, asp.net, iis, clone, dotnetnuke

I've tried many things suggested around the web and have not been able to clone a DNN site with total success (just partial, glitchy clones):

**On sandbox server:**

1. Back up DNN DB
2. Back up DNN files from IIS

**On production server:**

3. ​Restore DNN DB from step 1
4. Host DNN files from step 2 in a new IIS site, using same app pool & security settings, etc.
5. Do basic housekeeping, change DB connection strings in web config and update portal aliases, etc.
6. Log in to new DNN site on production, which should be an identical clone of the DNN site on the sandbox... *Doesn't work!*

***Is there no way to get this to work with DNN?***

Answer (score 0):

That process should work for dnn just fine.

What about the restore isn't working? Are you sure update portal alias and then start the application? If you update after the app starts you need to restart the app.

Comment: Premium 3rd-party modules w/DRM don't work properly, 1/2 the time pages load they only render partially, hitting refresh seems to help when this happens, the list goes on, and it's long.

Comment: Flash - your response makes it sound more like you have licensing issues

Answer (score 0):

I would also update the DefaultPortalAlias entry from the PortalSettings table:

*UPDATE PortalSettings
SET SettingValue = 'www.YOUR-DOMAIN-GOES-HERE.com'
WHERE SettingName = 'DefaultPortalAlias'*

Comment: Yes, that is one of my 'housekeeping' steps

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, the 'restored' database on the new site will no longer have the same (matching/mapping) GUIDs for the SQL loginname and username so the connection will not be established until the two are resynced (remapped). Use the following SQL Query to correct this:

```
USE DB_NAME
GO
EXEC sp_change_users_login 'update_one', 'USER_NAME', 'LOGIN_NAME’
GO
```

Hope this helps.